# RecyclerView changing height but child layouts not reflecting new size

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout

I have a horizontally-scrolling RecyclerView that has some initial height set on it, and on a user action, it's height changes. I want to have the items inside of the recycler use the new bounds of their parent, but instead they seem to keep the previously identified height.

A quick example:

```xml
<!-- RecyclerView's layout (the parent) -->
<ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline_top"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.30" />
    <Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline_bottom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.90" />
    <RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_manager="LinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/guideline_top"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/guideline_bottom"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
</ConstraintLayout>
```

The above recycler is going to have a height of 60% of its parent size.

And here's the layout of the viewholders:

```xml
<!-- Viewholder layout (the children) -->
<ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Test"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="At the bottom"
        android:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
</ConstraintLayout>
```

If I change the guidelines programmatically (after a user presses some button, for example):

```
// Change top from 30% to 10%, and bottom from 90% to 100%
// New size is 80% of parent
guidelineTop.setGuidelinePercent(0.1f)
guidelineBottom.setGuidelinePercent(1f)
```

The recyclerview automatically animates and resizes to be the correct size (80% of parent height), but it's child layouts are still laid out as if the recycler was the (now incorrect) 60% of parent height.

I've tried calling `recyclerView.requestLayout()`, but that doesn't seem to do anything. I've also tried calling `holder.itemView.requestLayout()` for all children, and that also doesn't seem to do anything.

Would anyone be able to tell me how to make the children resize themselves based on the new height value that the recycler has?

Edit: I can see that the child itemView heights -are- updated, but the positions of the items in the children are not behaving accordingly. I.e. the button that should be bottom-aligned is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix was to re-apply the constraints after the transition/animation was finished.

```
// Once the animation is done, for each viewholder:
ConstraintSet()
    .also { it.clone(constraintLayout) }
    .applyTo(constraintLayout)
```

Answer (score 0):

iam not sure but i hope it help

write this line after changing height : `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

`adapter` is your recyclerview adapter

Answer (score 0):

It might be that your adapter's `onCreateViewHolder()` isn't being called to build your views after you notify the adapter of your changes.

Try overriding your adapter's `getItemViewType()` which should force it to call `onCreateViewHolder()` when you update:

```
// Override this to force onCreateViewHolder to be called when appropriately notified
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position){
    return position; // Return any variable as long as it's not a constant value
}
```

Then, call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` after you've updated the size.